# Autoencoder bad reconstruction with low loss

Tags: keras, autoencoder

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]I train an autoencoder on my data. I define mse as loss function and it decrease to almost 0.005 for both train and validation during training so I conclude that the autoencoder trained perfectly but when I visualize my data, reconstructed data are not good and they are almost same for all data. I can not find out what is the problem?

Any suggestion??

Comment: Please, give us some illustration for your problem.

Comment: Probably there is a problem in your data generation process. Sharing your code will make it easier to help.

Comment: @AlexL I have some time series signals for each sample. I subsample this signals for each sample and concatenate them to create a ndarray. then I try to train an autoencoder on this data to extract features. I implement autoencodr in keras and use mse as loss function. autoencoder trained perfectly and both train and validation loss are lose to zero. but when I check samples and their reconstructed output, I got almost the same reconstruction for different samples. I could not find out why I got bad reconstructed data while reconstruction error is close to zero??

Comment: @pooyan I don't understand what do you mean by "data generation". I subsample some signals from dataset. I tried both simple and convolutional autoencoder and also sparsity but the results more or loss are the same

Comment: You should share some code here because there are several possibility about your problem. (eg. maybe because of some wrong coding, you are training your autoencoder using same data)

Comment: @pooyan the code is very long. I check this sort of mistakes. I check data in debug mode and every thing seems fine. besides I implemented autoencoder as a python class and use of this class for training an autoencoder for images of the same samples in dataset and every thing goes rights and reconstructed images are reasonably close to originals.

Comment: @SomayyehAtaeiKachouei you said you have the same reconstructed data for different samples. What exactly sample does the reconstruction correspond to? The first, the second, or may be random? If all of the decoded pictures are each time like the first sample, there may probably be some stuck in your decoder internal buffer or something like this.

Comment: @AlexL I added a picture, in that first 3 rows are some of my validation data and next 3 rows are their reconstructions. data are signals that I concatenated them on channel axis. I reshape data and show them as images. the trained model's mse is 0.003 but you can see that reconstructed data are almost equal and are not even close to the originals.

Comment: @AlexL I also add the same test that show signals as time series and you can see while mse is 0.003 for the network the reconstructed signals are very different from original data.

Comment: @SomayyehAtaeiKachouei take an attention to the peculiarities at the beginning and at the end of your reconstructed data. Simply speaking, the reconstructed signal jumps everywhere in the first and last point intervals. And please, give more exact data in your pics. Give also an illustration to the situation where everything goes right.